# How to get pictures from all sub folders in to 1 single folder?

Tags: finder, automator

I copied everything from a camera and now I have hundreds of folders like this:

```
Backup 01/AHJSKNXIPD/001.jpg
Backup 01/AHJSKNXIPD/002.jpg
Backup 01/AHJSKNXIPD/003.jpg
Backup 01/NQOPSORHEN/001.jpg
Backup 01/QUOZNDBEJR/001.jpg
Backup 03/EIRNEKQLDK/001.jpg
Backup 02/RNEJDKSOWE/001.jpg
```

Just an example (there are actually 100's, maybe 1000's).

How can I get all pictures in to a single folder so that they're easier to go through and sort?

Comment: For future reference, use Image Capture to import photos; it won't make that mess. In fact, if they're all still on the camera, that might still be quickest.

Answer (score 1):

The following **find** command will do this for you:

```
find ./Backup*/ -type f -exec mv {} ./all \;
```

The ./Backup* says to look in all the directories that start with the word 'Backup'. The -type f says to look for all files; the -exec switch executes the following shell command, which moves the found files (represented by {}) to a directory you should create (in this example, I called it "all"; create this with *mkdir all*). Note the escaped semicolon at the end of the line -- this is essential to tell the find command that this is the end of the -exec option.

Comment: Eh, no it won't. I just noticed that you would wind up with tons of conflicts, as you've got a bunch of files with the same name, just in different directories. Sorry...